# Create A Validity Check For TextFieldTableCell in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, tablecelleditor

I have some `TextFieldTableCell` which are for taking `Double` data type values. I want to validate them. If user give wrong data type as input or keep that field empty, I want to mark that `TextFieldTableCell` as

> **Background color Yello**
>
> **Text style color Red**

At the end of successful validation, I want that `TextFieldTableCell` normal again.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could achieve with soo many ways, and the so many ways has to do with the way you implement it in the `TableCell`, but it will be mainly dependent on the `DataHolder` `Object` you use to help with the `virtualization`

To do this you will have to create your `TableCell`'s `updateItem(Object,boolean)` to implement the updating of  the cell with respect to styles, etc, and it should be in relation with your `updateSelected(boolean)` even though one calls the other, or leave the two and use `updateIndex()` so something like this for your `DataHolder` `class`

```
private class CellDataHolder {

    public CellDataHolder (String a){
        value = a;
    }

    String value = "empty"; //this being the text to show
    boolean badMatch = false; //this being the flag to index whether the
    //text matches your preference
}
```

now in your cell, in one of those methods mentioned you add a check for your item for example

```
@Override
    public void updateItem(CellDataHolder item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(empty){return;}
        setText(item.value);//set your text
        if(item.badMatch){//check if the text fits.
            setStyle(wrongFormatStyle);//this is where you set your bad style
        }else{
            setStyle(normalyStyle);//the style you want
        }
    }
```

and then in your `StringConverter` you will use that to check whether your text is valid the reason you i feel you should use the StringConverter is that it can reduce the multiple calls `update...()` receives, those methods gets called soo many times is not cool to put a long much work there, your cell might look slow, so its better you put it here, for example

```
setConverter(new StringConverter<CellDataHolder>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(CellDataHolder arg0) {
                    arg0.badMatch =
                            arg0.value.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");//here you add your algorithm
                return arg0.value;
            }

            @Override
            public CellDataHolder fromString(String arg0) {
                getItem().value = arg0;
                return getItem();
            }
        });
```

you can also filter how filter when the check is to be called, whether a refresh is called or an explicit edit is being made. for example

```
setConverter(new StringConverter<CellDataHolder>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(CellDataHolder arg0) {
                 if(isEditing()){ //whether it is an edit
                    arg0.badMatch =
                            arg0.value.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");//here you add your algorithm
                 }
                return arg0.value;
            }

            @Override
            public CellDataHolder fromString(String arg0) {
                getItem().value = arg0;
                return getItem();
            }
        });
```

Here is a [full demo snippet](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Elltz/aoL4q)

demo preview
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hope? It was very much helpful. Thank you so much. :D